# PrimeNg empty message shown even if the data is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNg table to show the data and have added the empty message template like the following :

```
<ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
   <tr>
     <td>
         No records found
      </td>
    </tr>
 </ng-template>
```

and I am using lazy loading as the data is fetched from the server. I have added a loading flag, which is changed when the http call is finished. The code is as below:

```
this.myService
    .myHttpCallFunction(params)
    .pipe(
        finalize(() =>{ this.loading = false;}, 100)
    )
    .subscribe(
        (result: JsendResponse) => this.data = result.data,
         errors => this.errors = errors
    );
```

I am passing the `loading` flag to the table and it looks like the following :

```
 <p-table [value]="data?.data" [columns]="settings.columns" [loading]="loading">
```

Now it is showing the loading icon for sometime and then the empty message is shown for sometime. Then only it will show the actual data. This is actually confusing as the use might think there is no data as it is showing the empty message.

Comment: Can you please reproduce on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: What does the '100' do in the line `finalize(() =>{ this.loading = false;}, 100)`

Comment: it will set the loading variable to false. I have tried like the answer has suggested, but it also has the same result.

Comment: @HappyCoder I copied example on primeng and tried the same and it is working as expected. Could you share minimum reproducible source code on stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

Update your code like below

```
this.myService
    .myHttpCallFunction(params)
    .subscribe(
        (result: JsendResponse) => {
          this.data = result.data;
           this.loading = false;
        },
         errors => this.errors = errors
    );
```

Comment: I have updated the code like this. But still it shows the same message.